# Polynomials, fractions and factorisation

Tags: polynomials

How can I write this fraction $$\dfrac{x^3}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}$$ as something like this $$ \dfrac{A}{x-1} + \dfrac{B}{x-2} + \dfrac{C}{x-3}$$?
A,B,C would be nice to be real numbers. I tried doing it classically, but I failed. If I try to get the last form to common denominator I don't have any $x^3$ and well...it's not the right approach

Comment: You cannot, because the limits as $x\to +\infty$ of both expressions do not match.

Comment: You can't! For such a partial fraction expansion you need the numerator to have **smaller** degree than the denominator. What you need is $$\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x-2}+\frac{C}{x-3}+D.$$

Comment: However, you may express $\frac{x^3}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}$ as $$\color{red}{1+ }\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x-2}+\frac{C}{x-3}.$$

Comment: Already pointed out by others, but in other words ; first apply polynomial division.

Comment: Once you apply the suggestion of @JackD'Aurizio, the coefficients of each term are particularly simple to compute via residues.

Comment: First perform the Euclidean division of the numerator by the denominator to come dome down to the case of a *proper*  rational function (i.  e. $\deg$(numerator) $<\deg$(denominator)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ f(x)= \frac{x^3}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)} = \color{red}{1\,+\,}\frac{\color{green}{A}}{x-1}+\frac{\color{blue}{B}}{x-2}+\frac{\color{purple}{C}}{x-3} \tag{1}$$
with
$$ \color{green}{A} = \text{Res}\left(f(x),x=1\right) = \lim_{x\to 1}(x-1)\,f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3}{(x-2)(x-3)} = \color{green}{\frac{1}{2}}.\tag{2} $$
Similarly, $\color{blue}{B=-8}$ and $\color{purple}{C=\frac{27}{2}}$.

Comment: this is using complex analysis, right?

Comment: @DenisNichita: if you like, yes. But of course you may just ignore the residue written in $(2)$ and the given equality (as a consequence of $(1)$) makes perfectly sense even without it.